# How can I determine if there is more than one user on the Android Phone?

Tags: android, multi-user

My application needs to detect if the user has setup [multiple users](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user) on their phone. My application will be running from the primary user account. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Here are some options that I have ruled out:

The method [UserManager.getUserCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager#getUserCount()), is only available to system apps and requires the `android.permission.MANAGE_USERS` permission.

The method [UserManager.getUserProfiles()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager#getUserCount()) returns a list of [UserHandles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserHandle), but I am not able to identify if the `UserHandle` belongs to a profile within the user or a separate User?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know multiple users configured in device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018677/how-to-know-multiple-users-configured-in-device)